# Andengine: How to draw a transparent rectangle with rounded corners and border?

Tags: android, andengine

I've been trying to figure out how to draw a transparent rectangle with rounded corners and border with no avail.

Being new to andengine, I'm wondering if it is possible at all. Can someone please provide some pointers or help with a link to a sample. Wasn't able to find any when searching over the internet.

Comment: No, its not that easy. Can't you use some sprite? Drawing figures different that rectangle or line in andEngine is done through Mesh class, but it's not easy to draw circle. Depending on what you actullly need to do there might be some solutions. Any code you already tried?

Comment: i was looking for a supporting method/class but couldn't find. So currently trying with cornered rectangles but unable to make that too transparent. Am i missing something? What method should i call to make it just show borders and not have a fill color?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there is none. I think you have to draw your rectangles using lines (and add rectangle inside if you want to add some fill)

Comment: Yes, looks like that is the only option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There already `Rectangle` class in andengine..

```
Rectangle rec=new Rectangle(x,y,width,height,....);
```

For transparency:

```
rec.setAlpha(0):
```

Attach to your scene, if you are using rectangle as physics object like used for collision then create box body from `PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody();`

```
scene.attachChild(rec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Rectangle can you use a Sprite. Just create an image in Photoshop or another program, apply some transparency and export as .png. Then just load the image as Sprite.